# Random value into matrix (np.ndarray) at position from tuple obtained from np.where

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix with some zero

```
x=np.array([[1,2,3,0],[4,0,5,0],[7,0,0,0],[0,9,8,0]])
>>> x
array([[1, 2, 3, 0],
       [4, 0, 5, 0],
       [7, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 9, 8, 0]])
```

And want to random value into only a position which is not zero. I can get the (row, col) position as tuple from np.where

```
pos = np.where(x!=0)
>>> (array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3], dtype=int64), array([0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int64))
```

Is there a way to use `np.random` (or something else) for the matrix `x` at position from `pos`only without changing where is zero?

```
# pseudocode
new_x = np.rand(x, at pos)
```

Comment: well you can use nonzero() method to find all non zero indexes! checkout the details in answer!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you can use x.nonzero() which gives you all indices of array with nonzero values

and then then you just need to put random values at those indices

```
nz_indices = x.nonzero()
for i,j in zip(nz_indices[0],nz_indices[1]):
    x[i][j] = np.random.randint(1500) #random number till 1500
```

> you can find more about randint() here >>  [randint docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html#numpy.random.randint)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to replace non-zero value with random integer number.

You can use the combination of [numpy.place](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.place.html#numpy.place) and [numpy.random.randint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html#numpy.random.randint) functions.

```
>>> x=np.array([[1,2,3,0],[4,0,5,0],[7,0,0,0],[0,9,8,0]])
>>> x
array([[1, 2, 3, 0],
       [4, 0, 5, 0],
       [7, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 9, 8, 0]])
>>> lower_bound, upper_bound = 1, 5 # random function boundary
>>> np.place(x, x!=0, np.random.randint(lower_bound, upper_bound, np.count_nonzero(x)))
>>> x
array([[2, 2, 3, 0],
       [1, 0, 3, 0],
       [2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 4, 3, 0]])
```

Comment: I think a simpler storing of `mask = x!=0` and then using it for generating and assigning might be better.

Comment: @Divakar Yes you right, using mask is simpler. However, in this case, I prefer using the available function (numpy.place) that is intended to deal with this specific problem.

Comment: But I think it would be slower with the function overhead.

Comment: Storing and assigning new matrix can also take a lot of memory. If you dealing with a huge matrix.

Comment: There's isn't any new array. You do : `mask = x!=0` and then `x[mask] = np.random.randint(11,99,(mask.sum()))`. The mask is unavoidable anyway.

Comment: I miss understood it. If you do it that way, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

How about something simple like this:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 0], [4, 0, 5, 0], [7, 0, 0, 0], [0, 9, 8, 0]])
w = x != 0
x[w] = np.random.randint(10, size=x.shape)[w]
print(x)

[[2 2 2 0]
 [0 0 4 0]
 [1 0 0 0]
 [0 3 1 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do

```
x = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=x.shape) * (x != 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just index with `np.nonzero`

```
i = np.nonzero(x)
x[i] = np.random.randint(1, 10, i[0].size)
```

Note for reference that `np.nonzero(x)` <=> `np.where(x)` <=> `np.where(x != 0)`

Comment: This returns `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple`

Comment: Is `x` a list instead of a numpy array?  In your question it is an array.

Comment: Sorry. You are right. I wrongly created my array while testing. It works okay now.